# Array Checking the Duplicacy and Unique values, and also print them

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

We would like to know, how we can check the array(data) with array(keywords). We want to store that results into variable for further use.
Here we explain you in detail.

```
$array1 = array(John Wilkins, Poul Warner, Rodger Smith, David Bentham, David Wilkins, Brian Smith, David Warner)(Data)

$array2 = array(Wilkins, Warner, Smith, Bentham)(Keywords)
```

Here we would like to check array2 in array1. and store the result in variable, and print them later or at the end.

```
Checking Process will be....... 
Array2(Wilkins) checks all the items in Array1.
Array2(Warner) checks all the items in Array1.
Array2(Smith) checks all the items in Array1.
and so on...
```

Please help to resolve this issue..

Thanks 
ROD

Comment: `foreach` item in `Array2`, do something `foreach` item in `Array1`, so you'll have a nested `foreach` loop. May that be of any help?

Comment: We are doing that type of thing. we are not getting that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$matches = array();

foreach ( $array2 as $value2 )
  foreach ( $array1 as $value1 )
    if ( stripos($value1, $value2) !== FALSE )
      $matches[] = $value1;

// Just in case a record matched more than once.
$matches = array_unique($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array("John Wilkins", "Poul Warner", "Rodger Smith", "David Bentham", "David Wilkins", "Brian Smith", "David Warner");
$array2 = array("Wilkins", "Warner", "Smith", "Bentham");
$result = array();

foreach ( $array2 as $value ) {
    $result = array_merge( preg_grep("/$value/", $array1), $result );
}

$result = array_unique($result);

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => David Bentham
    [1] => Rodger Smith
    [2] => Brian Smith
    [3] => Poul Warner
    [4] => David Warner
    [5] => John Wilkins
    [6] => David Wilkins
)
```